# Drawing a text along a path in QuartzCore

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Say I have an array of points that form a line and a text. How can I go about drawing the text along this line in

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

of a UIView?

I am able to draw the path without a problem. Is there a standard method that I overlooked or a framework that would allow me to draw the text along that path? Ideally I would like to do this using only QuartzCore/CoreGraphics.

I tried calculating the width of each character and rotating every character. This kind of works, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant method.

Comment: I would go for the manual positioning and rotation of each character on the path, as you mentioned it.

Comment: If the line is a straight line, just apply a rotation & translation CTM.

Comment: @KennyTM the path will be composed of several straight lines with the text covering one or (probably) more segments of this path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can do this in Mac OS X, but the closest you'll come on the iPhone is CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances and this wont even rotate.

It shouldn't be too hard to use a loop and draw each character using something like the following. This is adapted from Apple's documentation and not tested, so beware:

```
CGContextSelectFont(myContext, "Helvetica", 12, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(myContext, 10);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(myContext, kCGTextFillStroke);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(myContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);

NSUInteger charIndex = 0;
for(NSString *myChar in arrayOfChars) {
    char *cString = [myChar UTF8String];
    CGPoint charOrigin = originForPositionAlongPath(charIndex, myPath);
    CGFloat slope = slopeForPositionAlongPath(charIndex, myPath);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(myContext, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slope));
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(myContext, charOrigin.x, charOrigin.y, cString, 1);
}
```

**Edit:** Here's an idea of the PositionAlongPath functions. Again, they aren't tested, but should be close. originAlong... returns (-1, -1) if you run out of path.

```
CGPoint originForPositionAlongPath(int index, NSArray *path) {
    CGFloat charWidth = 12.0;
    CGFloat widthToGo = charWidth * index;

    NSInteger i = 0;
    CGPoint position = [path objectAtIndex:i];

    while(widthToGo >= 0) {
            //out of path, return invalid point
        if(i >= [path count]) {
            return CGPointMake(-1, -1);
        }

        CGPoint next = [path objectAtIndex:i+1];

        CGFloat xDiff = next.x - position.x;
        CGFloat yDiff = next.y - position.y;
        CGFloat distToNext = sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);

        CGFloat fracToGo = widthToGo/distToNext
            //point is before next point in path, interpolate the answer
        if(fracToGo < 1) {
            return CGPointMake(position.x+(xDiff*fracToGo), position.y+(yDiff*fracToGo));
        }

            //advance to next point on the path
        widthToGo -= distToNext;
        position = next;
        ++i;
    }
}


CGFloat slopeForPositionAlongPath(int index, NSArray *path) {
    CGPoint begin = originForPositionAlongPath(index, path);
    CGPoint end = originForPositionAlongPath(index+1, path);

    CGFloat xDiff = end.x - begin.x;
    CGFloat yDiff = end.y - begin.y;

    return atan(yDiff/xDiff);
}
```

Comment: I guess the difficult part is finding the two functions originForPositionAlongPath, slopeForPositionAlongPath.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you tried is along the lines of what I added or not. If you give me an idea of why what you tried wasn't good enough, I'll see if I can improve what I've come up with.

Comment: I had previously only implemented a test case for a given simple path with two segments, but did manage to formulate the two general methods you wrote. I'll check them out later today. Thanks a million for your help. I'll be back with more feedback.

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm interested to see how well the final solution works.

Comment: Did this work out? Because I could use some help with a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Had to tweak a few things. The slope and origin functions have NSArrays that contain CGPoints, which is not possible since CGPoint is a struct. I changed those to standard C arrays of CGPoint instead and added a third parameter that is the length of the CGPoint array.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably irrelevant but you can text along a path with SVG (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextOnAPath), and the iPhoneOS supports it.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not exactly what I was aiming at as I would like to be able to do this within QuartzCore.

Answer (score 0):

Above example unfortunately didn't work as expected.
I have now finally found the correct way to paint a text along the path.

Here we go:

You cannot take this code 1:1 as its just excerpted from my application, but i will make things clear with some comments.

```
// MODIFIED ORIGIN FUNCTION

CGPoint originForPositionAlongPath(float *l, float nextW, int index, NSArray *path) {
CGFloat widthToGo = *l + nextW;


NSInteger i = 0;
CGPoint position = [[path objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];

while(widthToGo >= 0) {
    //out of path, return invalid point
    if(i+1 >= [path count]) {
        return CGPointMake(-1, -1);
    }

    CGPoint next = [[path objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue];

    CGFloat xDiff = next.x - position.x;
    CGFloat yDiff = next.y - position.y;
    CGFloat distToNext = sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);

    CGFloat fracToGo = widthToGo/distToNext;
    //point is before next point in path, interpolate the answer
    if(fracToGo < 1) {
        return CGPointMake(position.x+(xDiff*fracToGo), position.y+(yDiff*fracToGo));
    }

    //advance to next point on the path
    widthToGo -= distToNext;
    position = next;
    ++i;
}
}

// MODIFIED SLOPE FUNCTION

CGFloat slopeForPositionAlongPath(float* l, float nextW, int index, NSArray *path) {
CGPoint begin = originForPositionAlongPath(l, 0, index, path);
CGPoint end = originForPositionAlongPath(l, nextW, index+1, path);

CGFloat xDiff = end.x - begin.x;
CGFloat yDiff = end.y - begin.y;

return atan(yDiff/xDiff);
}


// IMPORTANT: CHARACTER WIDTHS FOR HELVETICA, ABOVE EXAMPLE USES FIXED WIDTHS WHICH IS NOT ACCURATE

float arraychars[] = {
0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    
0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    
0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    
0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    
0.278, 0.333, 0.474, 0.556, 0.556, 0.889, 0.722, 0.278,
0.333, 0.333, 0.389, 0.584, 0.278, 0.584, 0.278, 0.278,
0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556,
0.556, 0.556, 0.333, 0.333, 0.584, 0.584, 0.584, 0.611,
0.975, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.667, 0.611, 0.778,
0.722, 0.278, 0.556, 0.722, 0.611, 0.833, 0.722, 0.778,
0.667, 0.778, 0.722, 0.667, 0.611, 0.722, 0.667, 0.944,
0.667, 0.667, 0.611, 0.333, 0.278, 0.333, 0.584, 0.556,
0.278, 0.556, 0.611, 0.556, 0.611, 0.556, 0.333, 0.611,
0.611, 0.278, 0.278, 0.556, 0.278, 0.889, 0.611, 0.611,
0.611, 0.611, 0.389, 0.556, 0.333, 0.611, 0.556, 0.778,
0.556, 0.556, 0.5,   0.389, 0.28,  0.389, 0.584, 0,    
0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    
0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    
0.278, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333,
0.333, 0,     0.333, 0.333, 0,     0.333, 0.333, 0.333,
0.278, 0.333, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.28,  0.556,
0.333, 0.737, 0.37,  0.556, 0.584, 0.333, 0.737, 0.333,
0.4,   0.584, 0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0.611, 0.556, 0.278,
0.333, 0.333, 0.365, 0.556, 0.834, 0.834, 0.834, 0.611,
0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 1,     0.722,
0.667, 0.667, 0.667, 0.667, 0.278, 0.278, 0.278, 0.278,
0.722, 0.722, 0.778, 0.778, 0.778, 0.778, 0.778, 0.584,
0.778, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.722, 0.667, 0.667, 0.611,
0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.889, 0.556,
0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.556, 0.278, 0.278, 0.278, 0.278,
0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.584,
0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.611, 0.556, 0.611, 0.556,
                 };    

void o_DrawContourLabel(void *myObjectInstance, TransBuffer* transBuffer,     MapPainterIphone* mp,const Projection& projection,
                    const MapParameter& parameter,
                    const LabelStyle& style,
                    const std::string& text,
                    size_t transStart, size_t transEnd){
// HERE WE Initialize the font etc.

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica-Bold", 10, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(context, 0);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, style.GetTextR(), style.GetTextG(), style.GetTextB(), style.GetTextA());
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);

// Here we prepare a NSArray holding all waypoints of our path.
// I fill it from a "transBuffer" but you may fill it with whatever you want

NSMutableArray* path = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (transBuffer->buffer[transStart].x<transBuffer->buffer[transEnd].x) {
    for (size_t j=transStart; j<=transEnd; j++) {
        if (j==transStart) {
            [path addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(transBuffer->buffer[j].x,transBuffer->buffer[j].y)]];
        }
        else {
            [path addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(transBuffer->buffer[j].x,transBuffer->buffer[j].y)]];
        }
    }
}
else {
    for (size_t j=0; j<=transEnd-transStart; j++) {
        size_t idx=transEnd-j;

        if (j==0) {
            [path addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(transBuffer->buffer[idx].x,transBuffer->buffer[idx].y)]];

        }
        else {
            [path addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(transBuffer->buffer[idx].x,transBuffer->buffer[idx].y)]];

        }
    }
}

// if path is too short for "estimated text length" then exit

if (pathLength(path)<text.length()*7) {
    // Text is longer than path to draw on
    return;
}

// NOW PAINT CHAR FOR CHAR USING CHARACTER WIDTHS TABLE

float lenUpToNow = 0;

CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
NSUInteger charIndex = 0;
for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
    char *cString = (char*)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    cString[0] = text.at(i);
    cString[1]=0;

    float nww = arraychars[cString[0]]*8*1.4;

    CGPoint charOrigin = originForPositionAlongPath(&lenUpToNow, 0, charIndex, path);
    CGFloat slope = slopeForPositionAlongPath(&lenUpToNow, nww, charIndex, path);
    std::cout << " CHARACTER " << cString << " placed at " << charOrigin.x << "," << charOrigin.y << std::endl;

    // DO NOT FORGET TO DO THIS (TWO TRANSFORMATIONS) .. one for the rotation
    // and one for mirroring, otherwise the text will be mirrored due to a
    // crappy coordinate system in QuartzCore.

    CGAffineTransform ct = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform,CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slope));
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, ct);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, charOrigin.x, charOrigin.y, cString, 1);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, charOrigin.x, charOrigin.y, cString, 1);
    std::cout << " ... len (" << (int)cString[0] << ") = " << arraychars[cString[0]] << " up to now: " << lenUpToNow << std::endl;
    lenUpToNow += nww;

    charIndex++;
    free(cString);
}


}
```

Comment: I think we ended up using the `NSString` methods to determine the widths of characters with different fonts (e.g. `sizeWithFont:`). Our main problem was that `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` does not support non-latin chars.

Comment: I had the same problem with non latin characters. I fixed it using the following method:

Comment: NSString* strCC = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:label.text.c_str()];
    const char* plCC = [strCC cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];

And then draw plCC ... works like a charm